# How to get data into the view without foreach in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Controller:

```
public function contact()
    {   
            $data =array();
            $this->load->model('contentModel');
            $data['reachus']=$this->contentModel->reachusviewModel();
            $data['socialnetworks']=$this->contentModel->socialnetworkviewModel();
            $data['background1']=$this->contentModel->contactbackgroundviewModel();
            $result=$this->load->view('contact',$data);
            /*$this->load->view('contact');*/
    }
```

my model:

```
 public function contactbackgroundviewModel()  
    {  

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('contactbackground');  
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result=$query->result();  
    }
```

My view:

```
   <?php  
     foreach ($background1 as $row)  
     {  

            echo $row->image; 
       }
?>
```

My requirement is I have only just one value to be printed. how should I avoid foreach, how the data should be printed in the view?

thanking in advance

Comment: Use: return $result=$query->row(); in your contactbackgroundviewModel()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[->row()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)**. This function returns a single result row

```
 $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('contactbackground');  
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result=$query->row(); // return only single row
```

In view

```
 echo $background1->image; // without use of foreach loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line:

```
return $result=$query->result();
```

to

```
return $result=$query->row_array();  //only the first row will be returned and the return data will be array.
```

or

```
return $result=$query->row(); //only the first row will be returned and the return data will be object.
```

Comment: You can also use `return $result=$query->row()` if you prefer to work with an object instead of an array.

Comment: Yes. but i usually prefer array :) !! Anyway thanks for the suggestion.. I'll update my answer with both ! Upvoted your comment !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use

```
return $result=$query->first_row();
```

instead of

```
return $result=$query->result();
```

in your model

Online Codeigniter Docs:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score -3):

You can use `print_r($array)`.

This will output all the array

Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)