# Trying to get property of non-object error using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've problem with codeigniter. this is the message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: employee/detail.php
>
> Line Number: 15

I heve model like this:

```
public function getByID($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('master_employee me'); 
    $this->db->join('master_position mp', 'mp.mp_id=me.mp_id');
    $this->db->where('me.me_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    /**
     * [$data get data from database]
     * @var array
     */
    $data = array($id);
    $data['msg']            = $this->_get_flashdata();
    $data['rows']           = $this->m_employee->getByID($id);
    $data['position']       = $this->m_position->get();

    /**
     * [$html call all wireframe]
     * @var array
     */
    $html = array();
    $html['header']     = $this->load->view('admin/header',$data,true);
    $html['kiri']       = $this->load->view('admin/kiri',null,true);
    $html['content']    = $this->load->view('admin/employee/edit',$data,true);
    $this->load->view('admin/template',$html);
}
```

and view like this

```
<?php if($rows->me_photo == NULL): ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/upload/be/employee/default-no-image.png'); ?>" class="img-responsive" title="no-photo" style="margin-bottom:10px" />
<?php else: ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/upload/be/employee'.$rows->me_name); ?>" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:10px" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to solve my problem? Please

Comment: Have you followed name standardization and style guide rules `Some_model.php` with `class Some_model extends CI_Model{}` and `Some_other_class.php` with `Some_other_class extends CI_Controller{}` as described in [documentations](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html)? It is more important in versions 3+ (notice [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) rule)?

Comment: could you please tell which one is line 15 in your code above? This error means that you r not getting any record return by your model. What is me_name property in your view file?

Comment: or may be you are pointing to the wrong property(db column name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php if($rows['me_photo'] == NULL): ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/upload/be/employee/default-no-image.png'); ?>" class="img-responsive" title="no-photo" style="margin-bottom:10px" />
<?php else: ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/upload/be/employee'.$rows['me_name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:10px" />
```

It's an array. Not object. `->` stands for object.

You need to change `$rows->m_ephoto` like this `$rows['me_photo']`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query

```
public function getByID($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('master_employee me'); 
$this->db->join('master_position mp', 'mp.mp_id=me.mp_id');
$this->db->where('me.me_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

in in view use like this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    echo $row->title;
 }
```

**[read here i hope you will get the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184116/how-to-get-data-into-the-view-without-foreach-in-codeigniter)**